# Regexp to capture WHERE clause

Tags: regex, oracle

this question might look like its easy but to me it's not. Having couple of ddls I want to get their where conditions. So for:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_1,
                     COL_2,
                     COL_3)
SELECT 1,2,3 FROM DUAL WHERE (SOME CONDITIONS);

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL_1,
                     COL_2,
                     COL_3)
SELECT 1,2,3 FROM DUAL WHERE
    ONE CONDITION;

INSERT INTO TABLE_3 (COL_1,
                     COL_2,
                     COL_3)
SELECT 1,2,3 FROM DUAL WHERE
    ONE CONDITION OR SECOND CONDITION;
```

I need to somehow capture: 
(SOME CONDITIONS)
 ONE CONDITION
ONE CONDITION OR SECOND CONDITION;

What I thought would suffice: `WHERE(.*\n)*;`
But not only that but also a lot of other variations didn't. What do I do wrong?
The tool I'm using to test this is: https://regex101.com/

Comment: This doesn't sound like a meaningful BUSINESS problem. It sounds like your approach to SOLVING a problem, and it is almost certain that the approach you are trying to use is not the right one. What is the BUSINESS problem you need to solve? Why do you need to extract the substring that represents the conditions in an INSERT statement?

Comment: What if there are other clauses beyond the `WHERE` - e.g. a `GROUP BY`, or a (useless in this scenario but sometimes seen) `ORDER BY`? Or the query is a `UNION` or has a CTE or joins etc.?

Comment: @mathguy I agree that while this is unusual, there really isn't any other option. What I have to do is, later, probably by using some more regexps create DELETE statements that will contain these previously extracted conditions. I could do it manually but I'm dealing with so many tables that it would take hours to complete.

Comment: Also there will never be anything after the WHERE conditions @AlexPoole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE[ \r\n]*(.*?);`should work fine for you.
It matches everything behind the WHERE with possible not matched whitespaces or newlines until a `;` appears, least times possible (the `?`)

[see example in regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/CnvmwZ/2)

Also, you may include the s-Flag to include newlines with `.` (as shown in my example)

Your clause is the first captured group.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CnvmwZ/3 This also returns the `GROUP BY` and/or `ORDER BY` clauses and not just the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @MT0 True, but for such cases where it gets more complicated i'd try to do it with everything but regex. I assume OP has only such simple cases.

Comment: I'm quite new to the regexp world and I didn't know about s-Flag. It's truly amazing! Thank you that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Just wondering - what do you think `[ \r\n]` means in the Oracle dialect of regular expressions? Almost surely not what you think or expect.

Comment: I know that \n in oracle doesn't work and hence there should be chr(10). On the other hand you are probably more experienced than me and it's some trick. Am I right @mathguy?

Comment: Should the expression be used in oracle? I expected it to be used somewhere else in a console application or javascript or sth. If that's the case I'd have to correct it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expression using recursive matches of named groups:

```
WHERE\s+(?&TEXT)
(?(DEFINE)
   (?<WORD>        \s*[a-zA-Z0-9_,.=<>-]+? )
   (?<BRACKETED>   \s*\((?&NESTED_TEXT)\s*\) )
   (?<NESTED_TEXT> (?:(?&WORD)|(?&BRACKETED))+ )
   (?<TEXT>        (?:(?!\s*GROUP\s+BY|\s*ORDER\s+BY)(?&WORD)|(?&BRACKETED))+ )
)
```

(with the `i` case-insensitive and `x` extended flags)

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aUjIlo/2)

This is not supported by Oracle's regular expression functions but if you are trying to use another language's regular expressions (that do support this) to match Oracle DML statements then it could work.

It may need further work to exclude `UNION` or to parse sub-query factoring clauses or double-quoted identifiers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but unfortunately I'm planning to use oracle's functions. Nevertheless I truly appreciate it.